# Windows 10 Battery Saver option is missing

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery

In Windows 10 when using the balanced power config we can change the performance to power ratio from the quick settings for the battery. However, a couple months ago I noticed an option disappeared. The slider used to always have 4 positions, battery saver, better battery, better performance, and best performance. I was wondering why my battery life was lasting so much less long. I noticed no longer have the option to change the slider to battery saving mode, it has completely vanished. For a moment I thought I dreamt about the extra slider position, but I did notice there is no green leaf on my battery icon.

[image]

Battery saving mode in the action center is greyed out:

[image]

The internet did not show any information on this, nobody seems to either have this issue, or they don't know or care. The internet did provide me with images of what I remember the menu looking like. I actually never noticed the brightness button disappearing but seeing it again reminds me that it was indeed there, but has probably been disabled in some update.

[image]

You can see in this image, there are 4 positions, of which the lowest is power saving mode, this is missing from my device. The battery saver is very important for me, because it is the quickest way to disable the Gaussian blur effect in the acrylic elements, and put everything in low power mode, since my battery is at the end of it's life. I need every minute of power I can have. I want to ask 2 things. First, how do we get the brightness button back? Is there a registry tweak for this? And secondly and most importantly, how do I get battery saving mode back? I want a quick settings menu with brightness toggle, and 4 slider options.

Comment: Type battery health in the start menu. Did it go into Settings?

Comment: @John Thanks for the quick reply, I actually was just trying to get into settings but noticed something weird. I opened Settings > System > Battery and it just endlessly loads. It's a black screen with scroll bar and at the top a horizontal loading bar of small balls flying from left to right. Perhaps there is some issue with the registry/immersive control panel app data?

Comment: Try the initial operating system repair:  ......(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
  ....   If that fails do a Windows 10 Repair Install

Comment: Yes I was thinking of running the SFC after noticing that too. I should probably also run DISM first to make sure my component store is intact too as you said.

Comment: I have a real Windows 10 machine in my basement (instrumentation machine). The Battery Saver icon is still there in Windows 10. Now different in Windows 11.

Comment: Well both DISM and SFC didn't find any problems with my installation. I also renamed the app data folder under packages, but nothing changes anything. I'll keep trying stuff but I can't find any information about this issue online. Actually my battery has vanished completely even after restarting explorer. Very odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix Settings by removing it's data and going into Powershell and doing

`Add-AppxPackage C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel\appxmanifest.xml -Register -Disabledevelopmentmode`

followed by a reboot.
I noticed the battery saver appeared again and then went look at the screenshot of when it was gone and noticed the battery icon was showing a charger. I can't believe I didn't realize this immediately, of course battery saver doesn't work when your laptop is plugged in.
Unplugging enables this feature again:

[image]

However, I still wonder where the brightness toggle went and how to get it back, it was a handy feature to have in the same menu as the battery power slider so that I can change it all at once.